What is this? 'j1 = %d' % j1. Why isn't 'j1 = %d' , j1 enough?
Perhaps because I am coming to it from Java, it seems strange. In java, print("%d", aNumber) is sufficient to fill the %d with aNumber. Why isn't 'j1 = %d' , j1 enough?
I am doing the Coursera algorithms course and the test case for the assignment is failing in the Jupyter notebook. Unfortunately, there is no help in the course forums from the staff.
I don't understand what in the world this is - it looks like a string modulo an integer??:
'j1 = %d' % j1

TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-87cacde37648> in <module>       
      1 # BEGIN TEST CASES       
      2 j1 = findCrossoverIndex([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [-2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
----> 3 print('j1 = %d' % j1)       
      4 assert j1 == 1, "Test Case # 1 Failed"       
      5 

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType  



It'a way to format string in python

See  Old string formatting

Your findCrossoverIndex isn't returning a value.

I'm so glad that people sell courses to make money off teaching syntax that is like, what, a decade out of date

@user459872 perhaps because I am coming to it from Java, it seems strange. In java, print("%d", aNumber) is sufficient to fill the %d with aNumber.

In Java, that's a specific feature of printf() (and a few other specific methods) - you can't do it at arbitrary points in your code.  In Python, it's a feature of strings themselves, so you can use it anywhere.

I'm not sure I understand the question. Python and Java just have different features; is that what you were looking for? Otherwise, why were you expecting Python to be like Java?

@wjandrea yes, I was expecting the formatting operator to behave similarly. thanks,

That's because, even if you have a return statement inside your findCrossoverIndex, there may be a condition where the function is not returning anything, thus the NoneType part in your error message. Could you provide it for us?

print has little in common with printf. It's essentially a wrapper around an object's write method. str.__mod__, on the other hand, is very similar to sprintf.
